# jQuery .fadeTo add element

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Im trying to add a small .fadeTo effect on a small div object in my work but unsure if i can and where to add it. i want to add this effect to all of the divs. I would like it to .fadeTo (500)

This is a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd7L3/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').bind("mouseenter", function(){
        var color  = $(this).css("background-color");


        $(this).css("background", "#53b9ab");


        $(this).bind("mouseleave", function(){
            $(this).css("background", color);

        })    
    })    
})
```

the effect I'm looking for is going to be used for social media icons the exact effect i want can be found on these social media icons http://www.coletownsend.com

Comment: Where do you want to do the `fade`?

Comment: And *what* do you want to fade?

Comment: I want the mouseenter colour to fade in, and fade out when the mouseleave  not just be instantaneous

Answer (score 1):

You can use .[animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) jQuery function.

> Description: Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties.

See [this](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) exapmle.

I've edited your code. See the result [here](http://goo.gl/fOfmu), and check the HTML and Javascript code.

This is jQuery code:

```
var color;
var fadeTime = 200;

$('div').bind("mouseenter", function(){
    color  = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#53b9ab"}, fadeTime);
});

$("div").bind("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: color}, fadeTime);           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to apply it to hover function,

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    $("div").css("background-color", "orange").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $("div").css("background-color", "lime").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

according to your code you may adjust it like the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').bind("mouseenter", function(){
            var color  = $(this).css("background-color");
            $(this).css("background", "#53b9ab").fadeIn('slow', 0.7); 
            $(this).bind("mouseleave", function(){
                $(this).css("background", color).fadeTo('slow', 0.5); // partial fading
            });    
        });   
});
```

Comment: That made the div hover over instantaneous and fade out slow to the original background-color then fade out completely

Answer (score 0):

By adding those 2 lines to your existing code, you can achieve it, if I understood correctly what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').bind("mouseenter", function(){
        var color  = $(this).css("background-color");

      $(this).css("background", "red");
      $(this).css("opacity", 0);  
      $(this).fadeTo(500,1);


    })    
})
```

Comment: That worked with the effect I wanted thank you! But it only lasts for like 2 hovers. The 2nd or 3rd time I hover over .body it just goes back to being instantaneous. Not sure if that is just jsfiddle though. @EmmetB

Comment: I think that's because of your second `$(document).ready(function()` block. You should remove that block, and put things inside it to the first `$(document).ready(function()` block. (i.e. border color change)

Comment: I tried to do it all in one but i couldn't get the code to work with it. Got any tips?